# Using a pulse sensor with Arduino, is it possible to code in Actionscript?

Tags: arduino

I'm attempting to construct a program that will read pulse through a pulse sensor I have hooked up to my Arduino Duemilanove Board. Easy enough right? OK...but I'm trying to code it using Actionscript. I've already got the serproxy and all that mess running; Actionscript is talking to the Board. I just don't know how to translate the working pulse code that I have (below) from Arduino language into Actionscript.

```
long Hxv[4]; // these arrays are used in the digital filter
long Hyv[4]; // H for highpass, L for lowpass
long Lxv[4];
long Lyv[4];

unsigned long readings; // used to help normalize the signal
unsigned long peakTime; // used to time the start of the heart pulse
unsigned long lastPeakTime = 0;// used to find the time between beats
volatile int Peak;     // used to locate the highest point in positive phase of heart beat waveform
int rate;              // used to help determine pulse rate
volatile int BPM;      // used to hold the pulse rate
int offset = 0;        // used to normalize the raw data
int sampleCounter;     // used to determine pulse timing
int beatCounter = 1;   // used to keep track of pulses
volatile int Signal;   // holds the incoming raw data
int NSignal;           // holds the normalized signal 
volatile int FSignal;  // holds result of the bandpass filter
volatile int HRV;      // holds the time between beats
volatile int Scale = 13;  // used to scale the result of the digital filter. range 12<>20 : high<>low amplification
volatile int Fade = 0;

boolean first = true; // reminds us to seed the filter on the first go
volatile boolean Pulse = false;  // becomes true when there is a heart pulse
volatile boolean B = false;     // becomes true when there is a heart pulse
volatile boolean QS = false;      // becomes true when pulse rate is determined. every 20 pulses

int pulsePin = 0;  // pulse sensor purple wire connected to analog pin 0


void setup(){
pinMode(13,OUTPUT);    // pin 13 will blink to your heartbeat!
Serial.begin(115200); // we agree to talk fast!
// this next bit will wind up in the library. it initializes Timer1 to throw an interrupt every 1mS.
TCCR1A = 0x00; // DISABLE OUTPUTS AND BREAK PWM ON DIGITAL PINS 9 & 10
TCCR1B = 0x11; // GO INTO 'PHASE AND FREQUENCY CORRECT' MODE, NO PRESCALER
TCCR1C = 0x00; // DON'T FORCE COMPARE
TIMSK1 = 0x01; // ENABLE OVERFLOW INTERRUPT (TOIE1)
ICR1 = 8000;   // TRIGGER TIMER INTERRUPT EVERY 1mS  
sei();         // MAKE SURE GLOBAL INTERRUPTS ARE ENABLED

}



void loop(){
  Serial.print("S");          // S tells processing that the following string is sensor data
  Serial.println(Signal);     // Signal holds the latest raw Pulse Sensor signal
  if (B == true){             //  B is true when arduino finds the heart beat
    Serial.print("B");        // 'B' tells Processing the following string is HRV data     (time between beats in mS)
    Serial.println(HRV);      //  HRV holds the time between this pulse and the last        pulse in mS
    B = false;                // reseting the QS for next time
  }
  if (QS == true){            //  QS is true when arduino derives the heart rate by averaging HRV over 20 beats
    Serial.print("Q");        //  'QS' tells Processing that the following string is heart rate data
    Serial.println(BPM);      //  BPM holds the heart rate in beats per minute
    QS = false;               //  reset the B for next time
  }
  Fade -= 15;
  Fade = constrain(Fade,0,255);
  analogWrite(11,Fade);

delay(20);                    //  take a break

}

// THIS IS THE TIMER 1 INTERRUPT SERVICE ROUTINE. IT WILL BE PUT INTO THE LIBRARY
ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect){ // triggered every time Timer 1 overflows
// Timer 1 makes sure that we take a reading every milisecond
Signal = analogRead(pulsePin);

// First normailize the waveform around 0
readings += Signal; // take a running total
sampleCounter++;     // we do this every milisecond. this timer is used as a clock
if ((sampleCounter %300) == 0){   // adjust as needed
  offset = readings / 300;        // average the running total
  readings = 0;                   // reset running total
}
NSignal = Signal - offset;        // normalizing here

// IF IT'S THE FIRST TIME THROUGH THE SKETCH, SEED THE FILTER WITH CURRENT DATA
if (first = true){
  for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
    Lxv[i] = Lyv[i] = NSignal <<10;  // seed the lowpass filter
    Hxv[i] = Hyv[i] = NSignal <<10;  // seed the highpass filter
  }
first = false;      // only seed once please
}
// THIS IS THE BANDPAS FILTER. GENERATED AT www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/~fisher/mkfilter/trad.html
//  BUTTERWORTH LOWPASS ORDER = 3; SAMPLERATE = 1mS; CORNER = 5Hz
    Lxv[0] = Lxv[1]; Lxv[1] = Lxv[2]; Lxv[2] = Lxv[3];
    Lxv[3] = NSignal<<10;    // insert the normalized data into the lowpass filter
    Lyv[0] = Lyv[1]; Lyv[1] = Lyv[2]; Lyv[2] = Lyv[3];
    Lyv[3] = (Lxv[0] + Lxv[3]) + 3 * (Lxv[1] + Lxv[2])
          + (3846 * Lyv[0]) + (-11781 * Lyv[1]) + (12031 * Lyv[2]);
//  Butterworth; Highpass; Order = 3; Sample Rate = 1mS; Corner = .8Hz
    Hxv[0] = Hxv[1]; Hxv[1] = Hxv[2]; Hxv[2] = Hxv[3];
    Hxv[3] = Lyv[3] / 4116; // insert lowpass result into highpass filter
    Hyv[0] = Hyv[1]; Hyv[1] = Hyv[2]; Hyv[2] = Hyv[3];
    Hyv[3] = (Hxv[3]-Hxv[0]) + 3 * (Hxv[1] - Hxv[2])
          + (8110 * Hyv[0]) + (-12206 * Hyv[1]) + (12031 * Hyv[2]);
FSignal = Hyv[3] >> Scale;  // result of highpass shift-scaled

//PLAY AROUND WITH THE SHIFT VALUE TO SCALE THE OUTPUT ~12 <> ~20 = High <> Low Amplification.

if (FSignal >= Peak && Pulse == false){  // heart beat causes ADC readings to surge down in value.  
  Peak = FSignal;                        // finding the moment when the downward pulse starts
  peakTime = sampleCounter;              // recodrd the time to derive HRV. 
}
//  NOW IT'S TIME TO LOOK FOR THE HEART BEAT
if ((sampleCounter %20) == 0){// only look for the beat every 20mS. This clears out alot of high frequency noise.
  if (FSignal < 0 && Pulse == false){  // signal surges down in value every time there is a pulse
     Pulse = true;                     // Pulse will stay true as long as pulse signal < 0
     digitalWrite(13,HIGH);            // pin 13 will stay high as long as pulse signal < 0  
     Fade = 255;                       // set the fade value to highest for fading LED on pin 11 (optional)   
     HRV = peakTime - lastPeakTime;    // measure time between beats
     lastPeakTime = peakTime;          // keep track of time for next pulse
     B = true;                         // set the Quantified Self flag when HRV gets updated. NOT cleared inside this ISR     
     rate += HRV;                      // add to the running total of HRV used to determine heart rate
     beatCounter++;                     // beatCounter times when to calculate bpm by averaging the beat time values
     if (beatCounter == 10){            // derive heart rate every 10 beats. adjust as needed
       rate /= beatCounter;             // averaging time between beats
       BPM = 60000/rate;                // how many beats can fit into a minute?
       beatCounter = 0;                 // reset counter
       rate = 0;                        // reset running total
       QS = true;                       // set Beat flag when BPM gets updated. NOT cleared inside this ISR
     }
  }
  if (FSignal > 0 && Pulse == true){    // when the values are going up, it's the time between beats
    digitalWrite(13,LOW);               // so turn off the pin 13 LED
    Pulse = false;                      // reset these variables so we can do it again!
    Peak = 0;                           // 
  }
}

}// end isr
```

Sorry, I know this is long. Any help/advice would be much appreciated.

king28.

Comment: Maybe you should know that there is no such thing as 'Arduino Language'. It's an environment, based on C++. That code you write in the Arduino IDE is C++. There is no way to run actionscript ON the Arduino. Whatever you run on a PC that's connected to the Arduino is your decision, as long as it supports the communication protocol (like the serial port, maybe ethernet or some other kind). If the question is more specifically abuot the PC software, I guess stackexchange is a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

About five years ago I gave a presentation on [Arduino and Actionscript](http://tomaterial.blogspot.co.uk/2010/09/arduino-actionscript-resources.html) integration. You should find example flash files, arduino code and notes. Back then I was using [as3glue's serproxy](https://code.google.com/p/as3glue/downloads/list) so route the serial port data to Flash via Socket.

Since then I see AIR introduced Native Extensions which means you should be able to get away without needing serproxy. On a quick search I found this [as3-arduino-connector](https://code.google.com/p/as3-arduino-connector/) which should help with reading the serial data from your Arduino.

You should then be able to parse and visualise it as you like.